# Заменить ключ ассоциативного массива его значением

Tags: javascript, json

Как получить из такого объекта:

```
{
  '1': ['Яблоко', '600', 1, '59'],
  '2': ['Банан', '1000', 1, '59'],
  '13': ['Апельсин', '10', 1, '64'],
  '14': ['Груша', '7', 2, '64']
}
```

такой же, но заменив ключ строки значением из 4-го элемента массива и скомпоновав по нему, получая такой вывод:

```
{
  '59': [ ['Яблоко', '600', 1], ['Банан', '1000', 1] ],
  '64': [ ['Апельсин', '10', 1], ['Груша', '7', 2] ]
}
```

Получается только объединяя в строку и то с ошибкой

```js
var json = {
  '1': [ ' Яблоко', '600', 2, '59' ],
  '2': [ ' Банан', '1000', 3, '59' ],
  '13': [ ' Апельсин', '10', 2, '64' ],
  '14': [ ' Груша', '7', 3, '64' ]
};

var mags = JSON.stringify(json);
var results = {};
mags = JSON.parse(mags);
for(var i in mags) { 
    results[mags[i][3]]+=mags[i];
    //console.log(zakazs[i]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json = {
  '1': [' Яблоко', '600', 2, '59'],
  '2': [' Банан', '1000', 3, '59'],
  '13': [' Апельсин', '10', 2, '64'],
  '14': [' Груша', '7', 3, '64']
};

const results = Object.values(json).reduce((acc, value) => {
  !acc[value[3]] && (acc[value[3]] = []);
  acc[value[3]].push(value.slice(0, -1))
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(results);
```

```js
var json = {
  '1': [' Яблоко', '600', 2, '59'],
  '2': [' Банан', '1000', 3, '59'],
  '13': [' Апельсин', '10', 2, '64'],
  '14': [' Груша', '7', 3, '64']
};

const results = Object.values(json).reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value[3]] = [...(acc[value[3]] || []), value.slice(0, -1)]
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = {
    '1': ['Яблоко', '600', 1, '59'],
    '2': ['Банан', '1000', 1, '59'],
    '13': ['Апельсин', '10', 1, '64'],
    '14': ['Груша', '7', 2, '64']
  };

let result = {};

for (let key in data){
  let newKey = data[key][3];
  if(!result[newKey]){
    result[newKey] = [];
  }
  result[newKey].push(data[key].slice(0, 3));
}

console.log(result)
```